# How to correctly wait a function execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I've defined a function `obtainToken`. This function, send a request to a specific URL and return a token:

```
async function obtainToken () {
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
    await axios
        .post('***',{
            client_id: '***',
            client_secret: '***',
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        },
        config)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data.access_token
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
}
module.exports.obtainToken = obtainToken
```

As you can see, this function return the token (`res.data.access_token`)
Into the main file, I've tried to do:

```
async function initialize(){
    var x = await utility.obtainToken()
    console.log(x)
}

initialize()
```

The token value is `undefined`. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to nodejs, so I'm sure that the use of async functions is not correct...what's the right way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Not a js dev, but is't a `return`missing there?

Comment: You're mixing `async`/`await` with `then()`. Your code should be consistent and only use one style, not both at the same time, otherwise it's easy to get confused.

Comment: You need to choose between using await / async or chaining .then() .catch(), etc. see here https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/11/comparison-async-await-versus-then-catch/

Comment: Why are you using `multipart/form-data`  without a `FormData` object?

Comment: While there is a `return` inside, that's for the arrow function you're passing to `then()`. And in fact it could be simplified to `.then(res => res.data.access_token)`, removing even the visual appearance that the function could `return` anything. Then you could fix it via writing `return axios [...]`, and in fact you can remove the `async` keyword too (as you're not using `await` any more). Technically `return await axios [...]` would work too (with `async` of course), just that's unpacks (`await`) and repacks (`return` from `async`) a `Promise`, and these steps can be just skipped.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to choose between async/await or use then. do not combine the two at the same time.

```js
async function obtainToken() {
    let result;
    try {
        const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
        const { data } = await axios.post('***', {
            client_id: '***',
            client_secret: '***',
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        }, config);
        result = data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        result = error;
    }

    return result;
}

module.exports.obtainToken = obtainToken
```

Comment: My concern here is that the axios.post response and error are completely different and returning both can be an issue on the upper layer. I would suggest not wrapping the call and allow the exception to be thrown or to handle it in a different way.

Comment: coz ur obtainToken is no return.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the comment:

> ```
> .then(res => {
>     return res.data.access_token
> })
> ```

in your code has an arrow function in it, and the `return` returns from that function, not from `obtainToken()`.
It could be written as

```
.then(function(res) {
    return res.data.access_token
})
```

making it more apparent that it's inside a different `function`, which you could extract and give a name to if you want. Then this part of the code would become

```
.then(somefunctionwithaname)
```

and there would not remain any "visible" `return` keyword inside `obtainToken()`.

So the solution is to have one, the absolutely minimal fix would be

```
async function obtainToken () {
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
    return await axios             // <-- that's the missing return
        .post('***',{
            client_id: '***',
            client_secret: '***',
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        },
        config)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data.access_token
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
}
module.exports.obtainToken = obtainToken
```

However it has at least two points where it could be simpler:

1. `return` from an `async` function automatically wraps the result in a promise, and this code has just `await`ed for one. `return await <somepromise>` can be simply a `return <somepromise>`. And as `await` is not used any more, marking the function `async` becomes optional
2. an arrow function returning the result of a single expression (`x => {return x*2;}`) doesn't need a body, you can just write the expression itself (`x => x*2`)
3. it's a good practice to use semicolons, even if they're not absolutely mandatory everywhere.

---

```
function obtainToken () {
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
    return axios
        .post('***',{
            client_id: '***',
            client_secret: '***',
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        },
        config)
        .then(res => res.data.access_token)
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        });
}
module.exports.obtainToken = obtainToken;
```

`obtainToken()` still produces a `Promise`, so its usage as `var x = await utility.obtainToken();` remains ok.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of people talking about the best practices so you know that you should use one either .then or await/async but here is the solution for your code:

```js
async function obtainToken () {
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
    await axios
        .post('***',{
            client_id: '***',
            client_secret: '***',
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        },
        config)
        .then(res => {
            return res.data.access_token
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
}
module.exports.obtainToken = obtainToken
```